# What is the difference between -I. and -Ilib in Raku?

Tags: metadata, software-distribution, raku, module-search-path

I have a local distribution laid out as follows:

```
.
├── META6.json
└── lib
    └── Foo.rakumod
```

Both `raku -I. -e 'use Foo;'` and `raku -Ilib -e 'use Foo;'` compile and run, so which one should I use and why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another way of asking this question would be "What is the difference between -I $dir-with-meta6-file and -I $dir-without-meta6-file?". In this answer `-I.` will technically refer to `-I $dir-with-meta6-file`, and `-Ilib` will refer to `-I $dir-without-meta6-file`. Also note this covers `use lib '.'` and `use lib 'lib'`

The difference between `-I.` and `-Ilib` can be briefly be summarized:

- `-I.` will look to the `META6.json` for what files/namespaces are provided and their version/api/auth
- `-Ilib` provides all existing files and maps them to a predictable namespace (`Foo/Bar.rakumod` -> `Foo::Bar`) and will match any version/api/auth

Generally `-Ilib` gets used while developing, particularly when starting, because it is easier than manually adding/removing entries in the `META6.json` file. If you are writing a local application or something that is not intended to be installed this is mostly ok.

However! `-I.` should be preferred once a `META6.json` file has be created for the distribution. This can be slightly more work to maintain manually, but it has a few advantages:

- It provides some basic assurance that it will install; a common problem I see is modules passing their tests but failing to actually install because precompilation on install only has access to the files listed in the `META6.json` file.
- It allows mapping multiple namespaces to a single file (I'm not encouraging this).